# How to use multiple tilesets in a map?

Tags: tilemap, phaser, tilesets

I'm currently looking at this phaser example: http://phaser.io/examples/v2/tilemaps/blank-tilemap

Here, the author creates a simple tilemap editor. In line #33 he adds a preloaded image as tileset.

The problem is: the author adds only one tileset but I'd like to add multiple tilesets to the map (via map.addTilesetImage), switch between them and paint with the "current one".

I've read multiple times on the internet that it is possible to add and use many tilesets on a single map, but so far I haven't found any examples of that and the phaser docs also don't give that away.

Comment: just add a function which loads a different tileset on the top bar

Comment: what do you mean with "top bar"?

Comment: have you noticed the `createTileSelector` function that creates the so called "top bar" - the thingy on the top, that allows you to select tiles for drawing?